# Есть ли такие компоненты dll для сохрания состояния программы C#?

Tags: c#

Собственно, интересуют компоненты, реализующие save\load.

Comment: @anunak, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, состояние программы полностью сохранить нельзя. Например, открытые файлы, взятые блокировки, стеки всех потоков — всё это можно сохранить лишь глубоко системными средствами.

Обычно, однако же, достаточно сохранять лишь состояние некоторых объектов, и при рестарте программы восстанавливать остальное. Для этого традиционно используются [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter`, `DataContractSerializer`.